# How to grant privilige to a user to create only one connection at a time in a given database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The specification states - The new  user admin  must  have  the  rights  to  create  at  any  time  only  one connection  to the database.

Is there a way to add the number of connections allowed after we grant the create privilege to a user?

Comment: `grant usage on *.* to user with max_user_connections 1;` somethink like this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
create user user@'%' identified by password 'xxx' MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 1;
grant usage on dbname.* to user@'%';
```

this should work [Refernce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-resources.html)